# Remove div without moving the elements inside of it using jQuery unwrap

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the div that has class "form-group" but I don't want to remove the code inside of it. jQuery unwrap should do this but I'm not sure how to write the code.

```
<form class="navbar-form">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<button class="btn btn-primary modal-search" type="submit">
<span class="icon icon-search"></span>
</button>
</div>       
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the DOM, or just to `$.hide()` it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('.form-group').children().unwrap();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/DL2dL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also save the data of the div and then append it to the form once you're done. Here is a fiddle example for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/pPGj2/

The code was:

```
var dataContent = $('.form-data').html();
$('.form-data').remove();
$('form').append(dataContent);
```